# GeoIP C API build and patching error

Tags: patch, geoip, mingw-w64, msys2

I have been trying to build the api in (windows 7 64bit) with msys2 using x86_64-w64-mingw32 but i keep geting errors
note that this errors wont happen when i use 32bit nmake but i need to build it in 64bit using msys2 and x86_64-w64-mingw32
Please help me fix my errors.

This log is from the build:

```
$ ./configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc... x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
/bin/sh: /home/Me/missing: No such file or directory
configure: WARNING: 'missing' script is too old or missing
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking dependency style of x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc... gcc3
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc... (cached) x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
checking whether x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
checking build system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking host system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc... c:/msys64/opt/windows_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe
checking if the linker (c:/msys64/opt/windows_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /opt/windows_64/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/opt/windows_64/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... no, using cp -pR
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 8192
checking how to convert x86_64-w64-mingw32 file names to x86_64-w64-mingw32 format... func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
checking how to convert x86_64-w64-mingw32 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_msys_to_w32
checking for c:/msys64/opt/windows_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe option to reload object files... -r
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-objdump... no
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... file_magic ^x86 archive import|^x86 DLL
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool... no
checking for dlltool... dlltool
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... func_cygming_dll_for_implib
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-ar... no
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-ranlib... no
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /opt/windows_64/bin/nm -B output from x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /usr/bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /usr/bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-mt... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... no
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc option to produce PIC... -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC
checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc PIC flag -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC works... yes
checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc static flag -static works... yes
checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc linker (c:/msys64/opt/windows_64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... Win32 ld.exe
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking for byte... no
checking for ushort... no
checking for ulong... no
checking for u16... no
checking for u32... no
checking for off_t... yes
checking for size_t... yes
checking for ssize_t... yes
checking for uint32_t... yes
checking for uint64_t... yes
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for getopt... yes
checking for gettimeofday... yes
checking for pread... no
checking for vasprintf... yes
checking for vsnprintf... yes
checking for vsprintf... yes
checking for gethostbyname... no
checking for gethostbyname in -lnsl... no
checking for gethostbyname_r... no
checking for memset... yes
checking for memchr... yes
checking for munmap... no
checking for strrchr... yes
checking for socket... no
checking for strchr... yes
checking for strdup... yes
checking for strstr... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible malloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for GNU libc compatible realloc... yes
checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
checking for unistd.h... (cached) yes
checking for sys/param.h... yes
checking for getpagesize... yes
checking for working mmap... no
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating GeoIP.spec
config.status: creating geoip.pc
config.status: creating libGeoIP/Makefile
config.status: creating apps/Makefile
config.status: creating man/Makefile
config.status: creating test/Makefile
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands



$ make -i
Making all in libGeoIP
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Me/src/geoip-api-c-1.6.3/libGeoIP'
/bin/sh ../libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=link x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc  -g -O2 -no-undefined -version-info 7:3:6  -o libGeoIP.la -rpath /usr/local/lib GeoIP.lo GeoIP_deprecated.lo GeoIPCity.lo regionName.lo timeZone.lo
libtool: link: rm -fr  .libs/libGeoIP.dll.a
libtool: link: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -shared  .libs/GeoIP.o .libs/GeoIP_deprecated.o .libs/GeoIPCity.o .libs/regionName.o .libs/timeZone.o    -g -O2   -o .libs/libGeoIP-1.dll -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -Xlinker --out-implib -Xlinker .libs/libGeoIP.dll.a
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_check_mtime':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1134: undefined reference to `pread'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1172: undefined reference to `pread'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_GeoIP_inet_ntop':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:590: undefined reference to `__imp_getnameinfo'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_GeoIP_seek_record_v6_gl':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1209: undefined reference to `pread'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `get_db_description':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_get_name_v6_gl':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:2357: undefined reference to `pread'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_GeoIP_inet_pton':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:606: undefined reference to `__imp_getaddrinfo'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:617: undefined reference to `__imp_freeaddrinfo'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_GeoIP_seek_record_gl':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1299: undefined reference to `pread'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `get_db_description':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_get_name_gl':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:2298: undefined reference to `pread'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `GeoIP_open':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1494: undefined reference to `pread'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1547: undefined reference to `pread'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_GeoIP_lookupaddress':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1644: undefined reference to `__imp_inet_addr'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1692: undefined reference to `__imp_ntohl'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1677: undefined reference to `__imp_gethostbyname'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1692: undefined reference to `__imp_ntohl'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_GeoIP_lookupaddress_v6':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1707: undefined reference to `__imp_getaddrinfo'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:1714: undefined reference to `__imp_freeaddrinfo'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `get_db_description':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
.libs/GeoIP.o:C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: more undefined references to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription' follow
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `GeoIP_assign_region_by_inetaddr_gl':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:2030: undefined reference to `__imp_ntohl'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `_get_region_gl':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:2132: undefined reference to `__imp_htonl'
.libs/GeoIP.o: In function `get_db_description':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
.libs/GeoIP.o:C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIP.c:564: more undefined references to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription' follow
.libs/GeoIPCity.o: In function `_extract_record':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIPCity.c:97: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIP_country_continent'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIPCity.c:98: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIP_country_code'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIPCity.c:99: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIP_country_code3'
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIPCity.c:83: undefined reference to `pread'
.libs/GeoIPCity.o: In function `_get_record_gl':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIPCity.c:187: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
.libs/GeoIPCity.o: In function `_get_record_v6_gl':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIPCity.c:217: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
.libs/GeoIPCity.o: In function `GeoIP_record_id_by_addr':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIPCity.c:302: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
.libs/GeoIPCity.o: In function `GeoIP_record_id_by_addr_v6':
C:\msys64\home\Me\src\geoip-api-c-1.6.3\libGeoIP/GeoIPCity.c:320: undefined reference to `__imp_GeoIPDBDescription'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:387: recipe for target 'libGeoIP.la' failed
make[1]: [libGeoIP.la] Error 1 (ignored)
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Me/src/geoip-api-c-1.6.3/libGeoIP'
Making all in apps
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Me/src/geoip-api-c-1.6.3/apps'
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"GeoIP\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"GeoIP\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.6.3\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"GeoIP\ 1.6.3\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"support@maxmind.com\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -D__EXTENSIONS__=1 -D_ALL_SOURCE=1 -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS=1 -D_TANDEM_SOURCE=1 -DPACKAGE=\"GeoIP\" -DVERSION=\"1.6.3\" -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -DLITTLE_ENDIAN_HOST=1 -DHAVE_GETOPT=1 -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 -DHAVE_VASPRINTF=1 -DHAVE_VSNPRINTF=1 -DHAVE_VSPRINTF=1 -DHAVE_MEMSET=1 -DHAVE_MEMCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRDUP=1 -DHAVE_STRSTR=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_MALLOC=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_REALLOC=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_PARAM_H=1 -DHAVE_GETPAGESIZE=1 -I.  -I../libGeoIP -DSYSCONFDIR=\"/usr/local/etc\" -Wall   -g -O2 -MT geoiplookup.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/geoiplookup.Tpo -c -o geoiplookup.o geoiplookup.c
mv -f .deps/geoiplookup.Tpo .deps/geoiplookup.Po
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../libGeoIP/libGeoIP.la', needed by 'geoiplookup.exe'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Me/src/geoip-api-c-1.6.3/apps'
Makefile:429: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: [all-recursive] Error 1 (ignored)
```

And this log is from patching:

```
$ patch -F0 -i ~/src/geoip-api-c-1.6.3/GeoIPWinDLL.patch -p0
patching file GeoIP.c
Hunk #1 FAILED at 23.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 57.
Hunk #3 FAILED at 67.
Hunk #4 FAILED at 96.
4 out of 4 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file GeoIP.c.rej
patching file GeoIP.h
patch: **** malformed patch at line 183:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of few ppl `(adrien, alexey, LRN)` in `irc://irc.oftc.net/#mingw-w64` i managed to fix the problems
And also  i noticed that the patching wasn't needed 
So here i am going say what you got to do so you can build it in `msys2` using `x86_64-w64-mingw32`

---

1. Edit `geoip-api-c-1.6.3/Makefile.am` and add ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
2. Edit `geoip-api-c-1.6.3/configure.ac` and add AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
3. Edit `geoip-api-c-1.6.3/libGeoIP/Makefile.am` and add `pread.c` to `libGeoIP_la_SOURCES`
4. Once you added `pread.c` there you remove it from `EXTRA_DIST`
5. Run `autoreconf -fiv` or `./bootstrap`
6. `export "CFLAGS=-O2" export "CPPFLAGS=-DGEOIP_EXPORTS" export "LIBS=-lwsock32 -lws2_32"`
7. or you can try `export "CFLAGS=-DGEOIP_EXPORTS -O3 -I/usr/local/include" export "LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib -lwsock32 -lws2_32"`
8. `./configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 && make`

With that i managed to build it just fine :)